# How to use LINQ to only select if no results exist in related table?

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I have my tables:
aspnet_UsersInRoles
aspnet_Role
aspnet_Users
ApiUsers

I want to select only users that have the role "ProductOwner" and that currently do not have an entry in ApiUsers. The reason I am using a hasMany table right now is the schema might change and this makes it easy to adjust. Here is my current query:

```
    ddNewApiUserParentUser.DataSource = from u in dbc.aspnet_UsersInRoles
                                        where u.aspnet_Role.RoleName == "ProductOwner"
                                        select new { u.aspnet_User.UserId, u.aspnet_User.UserName };
```

This gets all users with the role ProductOwner however still gets them if there is already at least one row in ApiUser.
All the foreign keys are connected through UserId. How would I only get them with having a role name of ProductOwner if they have a 0 count in ApiUser (relation through UserId)?

Thanks so much,
Darren

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want something like this:

```
ddNewApiUserParentUser.DataSource = 
    from u in dbc.aspnet_UsersInRoles
    where u.aspnet_Role.RoleName == "ProductOwner" &&
        !u.aspnet_User.ApiUsers.Any()
    select new { u.aspnet_User.UserId, u.aspnet_User.UserName };
```

Comment: Thanks that is exactly what I was looking for, I also created the relationships.